# Join between Parent and Child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've 2 tables: `Parent` and `Child` with following data

[image]

[image]

Now when I execute the following queries:

```
delete from Parent where Id in(2,3,4)
delete from Child
```

The only record is left `Parent` table

Now when I execute the following query I don't get any records

```
select p.Id AS [ParentId],p.Name AS [ParentName], c.Id, c.Name from Parent p
Left join Child c on p.Id = c.ParentId 
where p.IsActive = 1 and c.IsActive = 1
```

And when I remove `and c.IsActive = 1` from above query I get the record in Package table, but I want to apply both the active checks. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`. Use

```
select p.Id AS [ParentId],p.Name AS [ParentName], c.Id, c.Name 
from Parent p
Left join Child c on p.Id = c.ParentId 
                 and c.IsActive = 1
where p.IsActive = 1
```

All filters of the left joined table need to be in the `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to treat both cases in the where clause condition (both when c.IsActive is null - missing row in child table - or is 1)

```
where p.IsActive = 1 and COALESCE(c.IsActive, 1) = 1
```

Comment: That will work too. Personally I find that super unreadable. If you read that in a year you have to look twice to get it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)